# nodejs - Why Node.js can handle large number of simulteneous persistent connections?

Tags: node.js, networking, tcp

I know Node.js is good at keeping large number of simultaneous persistent connections, for example, a chat room for many many chatters.

I am wondering how it achieves this. I mean anyway it is using TCP/IP which is encapsulated by the underlying OS, why it can handle persistent connections so well that others cannot?

What is the magic thing does it have?

Comment: @MartinJames: I think we've left the times when JS was the domain of script kiddies. No need for snide languageist remarks.

Comment: @Amadan The OP question is on the verge of being a business promotion.  It doesn't sound like 'A practical, answerable question based on actual problems faced', (faq). A languageist remark seemed appropriate.  I didn't downvote it or vote to close because there is a chance that it's a genuine question.

Comment: @MartinJames: No, if you felt a question does not belong to SO, a pointer to a FAQ is appropriate, not that. Would you have answered the same way if the question was about [node.cs](https://github.com/Rduerden/Node.cs), all other things being equal?

Comment: @Amadan - certainly not!  I would have found some other snide languageist reply.

Comment: @MartinJames I don't agree with you that my question is kind of `business promotion`. I ask this because I truly want to know why people all select node.js for simultaneous persistent connections while the asynchronous technique is not a secret any more. I don't know much about node.js but wish to know and understand more. That's why I asked this `general` question, instead of a `specific` one. But this doesn't mean I am not allowed, right? Sometimes you may wish to know a overview first before you dive in, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node.js makes all I/O asynchronous. It only runs in a single thread, but will do other requests or operations while waiting on I/O.

In contrast, classical web servers will not serve another request until the previous one is fully done. For this reason, Apache runs several processes at the same time; let's say there's 10 `httpd` processes, that normally means 10 requests can be served at any one time (*). If the processes take more time to complete, you will serve less requests - or will have to spawn more processes, even if the process is doing nothing - like waiting for the database to chew up and return data.

A node.js process, faced with a request that will go to the database, leaves the database to work while it goes to serve another request.

*) MPM makes this not quite true, but true enough for all intents and purposes.

Comment: I am very curious that if Node.js is just using non-blocking IO, why other giants such as Apache are not able to produce such a non-blocking thing? Why httpd isn't be modified to this kind of framework? and can they?

Comment: Security. Apache does what it does well; isolating requests from each other is a part of it. However, whenever you don't want requests isolated, Apache doesn't deal with it very well; although Phusion Passenger and FastCGI help. Bear in mind: Apache primarily serves static pages; everything else goes through CGI, or through plugins (Apache modules). Thus, optimising Apache for I/O is like optimising geese for pulling carts. (On the other hand, when speaking of Ruby or Python, both can do the same thing node.js does through their respective asynch libraries - EventMachine or Twisted.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the thing is that most web servers (like apache etc.. ) works using thread spawning, where they spwan a new thread for every incoming HTTP request. these threads are synchronous and blocking in nature => which means they will execute the code in the order it is written and any further computation will be blocked by the current I/O or compute task. Like if you want to listen for an event like - chat submission by a chatter you need to have a dedicated thread per user ( per user is necessary for maintaining persistent connection, there are few possible optimization techniques but still you can assume threads to be per user) listening to this event and this thread will be blocked waiting for this event to happen. So for any thread spawning and blocking web-server

Javascript on the other hand is non-blocking ( and conductive to asynchronous codes )by nature => here you register a callback for an event and whenever it occurs some the callback function will be executed. It will not block at any point waiting for this event.

You can find more about this by reading about non-blocking or asynchronous servers.

Comment: JavaScript is not asynchronous, node.js is. JavaScript is just rather conductive to asynchronous coding style (or rather, continuation passing style), due to functions' first-class citizenship; but there's nothing particularly asynchronous in JavaScript itself.